# Linux Partition on Different Architecture

Tags: arm, architecture, deployment

I have a **Cubieboad 2**, **Raspberry Pi 3** and an **Android Smart Phone**.

On Cubieboard and Raspberry, I write Cubian and Raspbian. On Android, I installed **Linux Deploy** and installed **Debian armhf**.

All of these boards are ARM.

Now, I want to run Cubian or Raspbian on Linux Deploy Application.

What's difference between partitions?

Comment: Should this be an edit to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460785/117549)?

Comment: Somehow, yes. Please help me.